# Understanding std::map::find

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to learn how to use std::map with functions. I am a bit confused about how `std::map::find` works in this regard. Here is a simple code where I use a Lambda function along with map.

```
auto Lambda = [](const int&a, const int& b) {
 cout << "\n Inside lambda \n";
 return a < b;
 };

std::map<int, int, decltype(Lambda)> expt(Lambda);
expt[1] = 2;
expt[10] = 12;
auto search1 = expt.find(1);
auto search10 = expt.find(10);
if(search1 != expt.end()) {
    std::cout << "Found " << search1->first << " " << search1->second << '\n';
}
else {
    std::cout << "Not found\n";
}
```

Here is the output that I get:

```
Inside lambda
Inside lambda
Inside lambda
Inside lambda
Inside lambda
Inside lambda
Inside lambda
Found 1 2
```

I am a bit confused about how `find` actually works in this case. Why do I get 7 calls of the lambda function even though I just have 2 keys in my map?

Comment: You have 2 comparisons for building the map, 2 for the first search, and 3 for the second search. What did you expect?

Comment: @n.m. -- obviously, he expected fewer than 7.

Comment: @PeteBecker Well I expect my next paycheck be 10x the last one.

Comment: If you print the values from the lambda you will see what's going on immediately.

Comment: cout may be buffered. Use a debugger.

Comment: @nm I got the following results when I print a and b : (10,1), (1,10), (1,1), (1,1), (1,10), (10,10), (10, 10) I am not sure whats happening here.

Comment: You want to know when one operation ends and the other starts, so print "inserting at 1", "inserting at 10", "finding at 1", "finding at 10".

Comment: Both OP and @n.m. are **wrong**, there are actually **8** calls to lambda. [Live at Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6e0UIKLVfjCWKwvm).

Comment: Inserting 1:
 Inserting 10:
 Inside lambda:
 10, 1
 Inside lambda:
 1, 10
Finding 1:
Inside lambda:
1, 1
Inside lambda:
1, 1
Finding 10:
Inside lambda:
1, 10
Inside lambda:
10, 10
Inside lambda:
10, 10
Found 1 2

Comment: @zett42 it depends on which implementation of the standard library you are using.

Comment: So which comparisons you don't understand or think are redundant?

Comment: Why (1,1) and (10,10) occurs twice ?

Comment: That's a great question. The answer is, because `<` cannot tell you that two things are equal in one go, you need to call it twice, once as `x < y` and once as `y < x`. If both return `false`, then and only then `x` and `y` are equal. So whenever `map` finds a key it needs to compare it twice.

Comment: @n.m. Interesting, [same code compiled with clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CXFf28E7MqLq5VBG) instead of gcc results in **7** calls to lambda.

Comment: @n.m. Why not make that an actual answer?

Comment: @zett42 that's because of libc++ not because of clang. libstdc++ seems to use one redundant comparison, which may be actually a bug.

Comment: @nm thanks for your answer and patience. I think I understand the underlying logic now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`operator <` cannot tell you that two things are equal in one go. You need to call both `x < y` and `y < x` in order to verify that `x == y`. So each time `map` actually finds a key, it compares the argument and the found key twice, once normally and once swapped around.

This accounts for double occurrence of `lambda(1,1)` and `lambda(10,10)`.

As for `lambda(10,1)` and `lambda(1,10)` when inserting an element with the key of `10`, this is needed because `map` *may* have to call comparison twice also when it fails to find a key (swap order of insertions to see that).

Comment: You could also mention that the exact number of comparisons for the insert rsp. find are not specified in the standard (only that it's O(log n)).

Answer (score 2):

Let me try to tackle this:

The point here is: you provide the definition of '<' operation only in map constructor. Map needs to perofrm the '<=' operation and it apparently does it like this:

```
bool le(left, rigth){
  return (left<right) and not (rigth<left);
}
```

so it it is sometimes enough to do just one `<`, and sometimes 2 are required for a single operation on map.

1. The first 2 comparisons are caused by the insertion operation. The map algorithm has to decide if the new element is `<=` the existing one. It performs 2 `<` comparisons in order to find out (`new<old and old>new`). (Notice that if you insert 10 first, and then 1, you will only get one comparison, since the first of them `new<old` would yield the unambigous result (true)).
2. The first find executes the lambda 2 times for the same reason. The first check `<` returns false, so it needs to do the second one, with the swapped arguments to learn if the values are equal or not.
3. Once again, same story...